# Angular Bootstrap multiple typehead component flicks

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap angular](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) typehead. For single use, it is working fine but when I am trying to create one more, it is flicking another typehead dropdown. As shown in the screenshot I select focused on country and the nationality's drop-down open and close suddenly. It's vice-versa.

[image]

.ts code.

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbTypeahead} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

const country = ["United States", "China", "Japan", "Germany", ]
const nationality = ['American', 'Indian', 'Japanese', 'Chinese','Spanish'];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accommodation',
  templateUrl: './accommodation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accommodation.component.css']
})
export class AccommodationComponent {


  model: any;
  model1: any;

  @ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  searchCountry = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200).distinctUntilChanged()
      .merge(this.focus$)
      .merge(this.click$.filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()))
      .map(term => (term === '' ? country : country.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10));

  searchNationality = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200).distinctUntilChanged()
      .merge(this.focus$)
      .merge(this.click$.filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()))
      .map(term => (term === '' ? nationality : nationality.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10));


}
```

html code

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input placeholder="Country" 
              id="countrySearch"
              type="text"
              name="country" 
              class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="model"
              [ngbTypeahead]="searchCountry"
              (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
              (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
              #instance="ngbTypeahead"
            />              

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">

        <input placeholder="Nationality" 
          id="nationalitySearch"
          type="text"
          name="Nationality" 
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="model1"
          [ngbTypeahead]="searchNationality"
          (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
          (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
          #instance="ngbTypeahead"
        />                  

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
```

What I am doing wrong in my code ? I created two model and added different id as well. still it flicks

Answer (score 2):

We need to create differently click and focus object.

```
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  focus1$ = new Subject<string>();
  click1$ = new Subject<string>();      

  focus2$ = new Subject<string>();
  click2$ = new Subject<string>();
```

It solved.

Comment: helped me, but there is more code that i needed,
you need to change the variables in multiple places